# Azure component that compares 2 word documents?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, architecture, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-services

I am looking to build a solution where we can compare (Automated) a word document we email to a client to the word document the client emails us back.

Any suggestions please, we will be using MS Azure to create the solution.

Comment: Here a list of the Azure services: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of a direct automation of this feature you can use an indirect route to approach the solution.

**Note**:

- This solution invokes Word using COM automation. Hence this is expected to be running on a VM that has word installed.
- Since this solution simplifies the content that is being compared, it might lose the details you might want to show up in your comparison.

You can create a PowerShell script that does the following

1. Convert the documents to a simpler (txt) format - See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bshukla/how-to-convert-a-word-document-to-other-formats-using-powershell) or [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/48nfes/saveas_all_doc_files_in_folder_to_txt_files/).
2. Compare the text files - See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-1---compare-the-content-of-two-text-files).

The powershell script will get the comparison done. After that its up to how much fancy you want to get when exposing this functionality outside that VM. e.g. You could create an HTTP invokable API that can call this Powershell script and return results.

Answer (score -2):

I think your best bet would be using Microsoft Azure Logic Apps! Azure Logic Apps allows you to develop advanced automation workflows on the cloud and it supports [a vast array of connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) out of the box including email triggers and the Microsoft Word Connector. If that's not enough then, you could even [develop your own connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/custom-connector-overview) too...

Comment: Please don't post just link-only answers. Also, there's no way to answer this question objectively, as there is no code shown by the OP, no specifics. And... you still haven't answered the question of how to compare two documents (not that you should - the original question is too broad, but... "use Logic Apps" doesn't solve the problem).